# Let a and b be two orthonognal null vectors. Prove that every vector in the subspace spanned by a and b is null

Tags: linear-algebra

$X= \sigma(2x + x^{2}n -\bar n)$ Where X is a null vector. 
  x= $e_1,e_2,e_3$ vectors. n is a vector and $\bar n$ is also a vector. 
 $\sigma$ is a scalar. If $x^{2}=0$ and x is a vector in $R^{5}$, it can be returned in the above formula 
  How can I prove that?

Comment: OP, your title makes sense but I have no idea what is going on in your question. I'm just going to ignore it.

Comment: are e1, e2, e3 supposed to be basis vectors? is n bar supposed to be a type of conjugate of n?

Comment: my question states that if X equation equals zero then its a null vector. I had those in my notes

Comment: n bar was stated in my notes to be a vector, and e1 e2 and e3 are vectors. It goes next to the 2 only

Comment: Nothing in your question makes any sense to me.

Comment: you mean the equation I put up for that big X?

Comment: I mean *nothing* in your question makes any sense to me.

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: If x is a 3-dimensional vector then x=$x^1e_1+x^2e_2+x^3e_3$

Comment: my professor decided we didn't need a book but he gets his questions from the geometric Algebra for computer science  by Leo Dorst et al, Elsevier

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $V$ is vector space with a symmetric bilinear form $B(u,v)$, in which case there is an associated quadratic form $Q(u)=B(u,u)$, and further assume that $a,b\in V$ are null vectors (meaning $Q(a)=0$ and $Q(b)=0$) and are orthogonal (meaning $B(a,b)=0$).

For any scalars $\lambda,\mu$ try computing $Q(\lambda a+\mu b)$ by rewriting it using $B$ and then using the distributive property of $B$.

Comment: you should probably take a look at Geometric Algebra for Computer Science by Leo Dorst before doing anything more. I clicked on the pdf link I found, it went directly to my Download folder rather than appearing onscreen. I don't think it was the whole book, but the table of contents is huge and revealing.

Comment: I do not have that book currently. did you google it?

Comment: Hmmm, Arctic. Looking at your questions and answers, interpreting this book may be quite enjoyable for you. Not sure what percentage of it can be successfully downloaded

Comment: Ok. My professor uses that book and lecture us from that. He didn't require us to buy it

Comment: @behold, given that you seem to have no idea what is going on, I suggest you buy the book. I have tutored college kids being taught by professors who were re-writing the subject matter and used no other book. Ugly.  And yes, I just put the title you said into Google. It seems the book is probably free if you are a member of the ACM. I am not.

Comment: @WillJagy One hundred percent. I'll look through it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after reviewing @artic tern suggestion, I stated c is arbitrary on a plane with a and b. 
 Also c is a linear combination of a and b. so a is perpendicular to b, $a^{2}=0$ and $b^{2}=0$ 
 So 
 $c=\lambda a+\mu b$ 
 $c^{2}=(\lambda a+ \mu b)^{2}$ 
 $c^{2}=(\lambda a+ \mu b) (\lambda a+ \mu b)$ 
 $c^{2}= \lambda^{2} a^{2} + \lambda a \mu b + \mu b  \lambda a + \mu^{2} b^{2}$ 
 $c^{2}= 2 \lambda \mu(a \cdot b)$ hence, dot product of a and b is $0$ 
 $c^{2}= 2 \lambda \mu \cdot 0$ 
 $c^{2}= 0$,  c is null 
 This is my best answer